# Can't find the missing 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

Tags: reactjs

I understand each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop but I can't seem to figure out which child needs the `key` prop in this scenario. Please help.

[image: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.]

```
<Container className="!py-0">
            <nav className="my-4">
                <Disclosure>
                    {({ open }) => (
                        <>
                            <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-between md:gap-10 lg:flex-nowrap">
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full lg:w-auto">
                                    <Link href="/">
                                        <a className="w-28 dark:hidden">
                                            {props.logo ? (
                                                <Image
                                                    {...GetImage(
                                                        props.logo
                                                    )}
                                                    alt="Logo"
                                                    sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 200px"
                                                    priority={true}
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <span className="block text-center">
                                                    Explore A.I. Today
                                                </span>
                                            )}
                                        </a>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link href="/">
                                        <a className="hidden w-28 dark:block">
                                            {props.logoalt ? (
                                                <Image
                                                    {...GetImage(
                                                        props.logoalt
                                                    )}
                                                    alt="Logo"
                                                    sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw, 200px"
                                                    priority={true}
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <span className="block text-center">
                                                    Explore A.I. Today
                                                </span>
                                            )}
                                        </a>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Disclosure.Button
                                        aria-label="Toggle Menu"
                                        className="px-2 py-1 ml-auto text-gray-500 rounded-md lg:hidden focus:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-300 ">
                                        <svg
                                            className="w-6 h-6 fill-current"
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                            {open && (
                                                <path
                                                    fillRule="evenodd"
                                                    clipRule="evenodd"
                                                    d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828 4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                            {!open && (
                                                <path
                                                    fillRule="evenodd"
                                                    d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
                                                />
                                            )}
                                        </svg>
                                    </Disclosure.Button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                                    <div className="flex-col items-center hidden w-full lg:flex lg:flex-row lg:w-auto ">
                                        {menu.map((item, index) => (
                                            <>
                                                {item.children &&
                                                item.children.length >
                                                    0 ? (
                                                    <DropdownMenu
                                                        key={index}
                                                        menu={item}
                                                        items={
                                                            item.children
                                                        }
                                                        mobile={
                                                            props.mobile
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                ) : (
                                                    <Link
                                                        key={index}
                                                        href={
                                                            item.href
                                                        }>
                                                        <a
                                                            className=" py-2 px-5 font-medium text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-500 outline-none focus-visible:text-blue-500 focus-visible:ring-2 rounded-full ring-blue-100"
                                                            target={
                                                                item.external
                                                                    ? "_blank"
                                                                    : ""
                                                            }
                                                            rel={
                                                                item.external
                                                                    ? "noopener"
                                                                    : ""
                                                            }>
                                                            {
                                                                item.label
                                                            }
                                                        </a>
                                                    </Link>
                                                )}
                                            </>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="hidden lg:block">
                                        <form
                                            action="/search"
                                            method="GET">
                                            <SearchInput placeholder="Search Blog" />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <Disclosure.Panel>
                                <div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-start order-2 w-full mt-5 -ml-5 lg:hidden">
                                    {menu.map((item, index) => (
                                        <>
                                            {item.children &&
                                            item.children.length >
                                                0 ? (
                                                <DropdownMenu
                                                    key={index}
                                                    menu={item}
                                                    items={
                                                        item.children
                                                    }
                                                    mobile={true}
                                                />
                                            ) : (
                                                <Link
                                                    key={index}
                                                    href={item.href}>
                                                    <a
                                                        className=" py-2 px-5   text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 hover:text-blue-500 outline-none focus-visible:text-blue-500 focus-visible:ring-2 rounded-full ring-blue-100"
                                                        target={
                                                            item.external
                                                                ? "_blank"
                                                                : ""
                                                        }
                                                        rel={
                                                            item.external
                                                                ? "noopener"
                                                                : ""
                                                        }>
                                                        {item.label}
                                                    </a>
                                                </Link>
                                            )}
                                        </>
                                    ))}
                                    <div className="px-5 mt-2">
                                        <form
                                            action="/search"
                                            method="GET">
                                            <SearchInput placeholder="Search Blog" />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Disclosure.Panel>
                        </>
                    )}
                </Disclosure>
            </nav>
        </Container>
```